# Print single entry match from array with php csv

Tags: php, arrays, csv, fopen

I have the following code which I am trying to compare a title in a csv file & pull back the appropriate price (in the csv) depending on the title:

```
<a class="Title" href="<?php echo $item->link;?>">
   <?php echo $item->title;?> <!--country title-->
</a>
<?php
       $pricelist = array();
       if (($handle = fopen("townprices.csv", "r")) !== FALSE)
       {
          while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
          {
             $pricelist[] = $data;
          }
          fclose($handle);
       }
       echo '<pre>'; print_r($pricelist); echo '</pre>';
?>
```

CSV contents:

```
Spain, 250
France, 350
Germany, 150
```

(town/title, price)

This bring back the following array from my csv:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Spain
            [1] =>  250
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => France
            [1] =>  350
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Germany
            [1] =>  150
        )
)
```

What I now need to do is just echo the right price, rather than

```
echo '<pre>'; print_r($pricelist); echo '</pre>';
```

So I need to create an if statement, something like:

if $item->title = Spain, print 250

But I am stuck on how to do this.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: `foreach ($pricelist as $value) { ... }`?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should index your CSV.

Let me give you an example.

```
$pricelist = array();
if (($handle = fopen("townprices.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
  while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $pricelist[$data[0]] = $data[1];
  }
  fclose($handle);
}
```

So

```
echo $pricelist['Spain']; // Would give 250
```

Comment: an example would be great... I'm stuck on passing this array as a variable into my view... so if title = Spain - echo 250

Comment: brillaint... so can I do this to match the country in the csv 
<?php echo $pricelist['$item->title']; ?>

Comment: Yes without the quotes around `$item->title` like `<?php echo $pricelist[$item->title] ?>`. Not tested but should work

Answer (score 1):

To list all prices, just do this:

```
foreach ($pricelist as $line) {
    echo $line[0].": &euro; ".$line[1]."<br />";
}
```

To find the price for a certain country, do this:

```
foreach ($pricelist as $line) {
    if($line[0] == "Spain") echo $line[1];
}
```

This will get slow on large source files though.